# mediaCapture work in background task WP 8.1

Tags: camera, windows-phone-8.1, background-task

Faced with the problem of initialization mediaCapture in the background task. The API says that mediaCapture does not support in the background, but I've seen a couple of WP 8.1 applications that implement this functionality, just interested in working with the freezing of the screen.
Here is the code that works well when running applications

```
public async Task Initialize()
{
    var cameraId = await GetCameraId(Panel.Back);
    if(cameraId != null)
    {
        var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
        {
            VideoDeviceId = cameraId.Id
        };

        if(this.mediaCapture == null)
        {
            this.mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
        }

        try
        {
            await this.mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);
        }
        catch(Exception) { }
        this.torchControl = this.mediaCapture?.VideoDeviceController?.TorchControl;
        this.IsSupported = this.torchControl != null && this.torchControl.Supported;
    }
}

public void TurnOn(float powerPercent)
{
    if(this.torchControl != null)
    {
        if(this.torchControl.PowerSupported)
        {
            this.torchControl.PowerPercent = powerPercent;
        }

        this.torchControl.Enabled = true;
        SettingsProvider.Instance.IsFlashlightOn = this.torchControl.Enabled;
    }
}
private static async Task<DeviceInformation> GetCameraId(Panel desiredCamera)
{
    var deviceId = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);
    return deviceId?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EnclosureLocation != null && x.EnclosureLocation.Panel == desiredCamera);
}
public void ClearMediaCapture()
{
    if(this.torchControl.Enabled)
    {
        this.TurnOff();
    }

    this.mediaCapture?.Dispose();
    this.mediaCapture = null;
}
```

Looking for examples of implementation or articles. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find the way to use mediaCaptura in the background task?